# Strict-Transport-Security: the site specified a header that could not be parsed successfully

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, strict

I made my PHP site live today; on localhost everything is working fine like registrations, but on the live site, they are not working.

I am using Ajax and jQuery to post data. Using FireFox's "inspect element" feature I see:

> Strict-Transport-Security: the site specified a header that could not be parsed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Strict Transport Policy header added from your server, should have the required format like

Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload

Any other format will not be parseable by the browser. More info about this header can be found [here](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html#examples)